# Docker image fails to build on Live but fine on Dev

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have a strange issue with Docker.

This is the Dockerfile in question.

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python-lxml \
    python-dev \
    python-pip \
    python-cffi \
    libcairo2 \
    libpango1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0.0 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libffi-dev \
    mysql-client \
    shared-mime-info

# ... further docker file rules, which doesn't get run cause apt-get fails
```

The problem I'm having is that on my development machine, this Dockerfile builds
perfectly fine, but on our live servers it's suddenly failing (worked in the
past), with `E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate`.

I thought the point of Docker is that everything runs using the same image and
that you shouldn't run into issues like this.

Why is this the case and what can I do to fix it from here so that it runs the
same on both dev and live?

Comment: Are you sure you have Internet access without a proxy on your production Server? What does the output of apt(-get) update show?

Comment: all the other packages are downloaded and installed fine. It's only `mysql-client`, in other words, if I comment out mysql-client, image builds.

Comment: If you set up a Docker registry, and `docker push` the successfully-built image there, then the remote system can `docker pull` it and won't have to repeat this step.

Comment: also fails on my machine.  not sure how your dev machine managed to build it

Comment: "I thought the point of Docker is that everything runs using the same image".  That's not what you're doing here: you're rebuilding the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using image `python` with tag `2.7`, however this tag is a *"shared"* tag as per [Python readme on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) which is changing other time: right now `python:2.7` is shared with Python `python:2.7.16` and `python:2` but previously it was probably shared with `python:2.7.15`, `python:2.7.14` etc. (in other words, `python:2.7` is following `python:2.7.x` as it upgrades)

Your machine and live server probably pulled the image at a different time and now have a different image tagged `2.7`. The "shared" tags seems to be like `latest` tags and may point to newer images as they are released.

What you can do:

- Enforce image pull when building even if image is already present (using [`docker build` with `--pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) option
- Use a documented **Simple tag** instead, these should be more consistent (such as `python:2.7.16-alpine3.9`)
- Do not re-build images during your release process, only build once and use the same image in your local and live environment (see below)

---

EDIT: this can be put into evidence with:

```
docker images --filter "reference=python" --digests --format "{{.Digest}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}"
sha256:7a61a96567a2b2ba5db636c83ffa18db584da4024fa5839665e330934cb6b2b2 python:2
sha256:7a61a96567a2b2ba5db636c83ffa18db584da4024fa5839665e330934cb6b2b2 python:2.7
sha256:7a61a96567a2b2ba5db636c83ffa18db584da4024fa5839665e330934cb6b2b2 python:2.7.16
sha256:39224960015b9c0fce12e08037692e8a4be2e940e73a36ed0c86332ce5ce325b python:2.7.15
```

To precise on:

> I thought the point of Docker is that everything runs using the same
>   image and that you shouldn't run into issues like this.
>
> Why is this the case and what can I do to fix it from here so that it runs the same on both dev and live?

Yes, and the recommended pattern is *build image once and use that same image trough all your release process* - this ensure you have the exact same context (packages, code, etc.) from development to production. You should not re-build your image from scratch on your live server, but ideally build it during your development phase and use that same image for testing and deploying.

Comment: Thx this is a good explanation and didn't think about the --pull option. Also, your (and others') comments on not re-building images is very valid, and I'll look at changing the deploy process to take this into account.

Answer (score 2):

Python:2.7 is now based on Debian Buster. There is no mysql-client apt package, considered https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql-client